# Correct grammar when listing objects with an attribute

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, lists

I have three cars, all of them are white. I wish to form a sentence where I list the cars separately as: first, second and third, and then say they are all white. I'm unsure what is the correct form:

1. First, second and third car are white.
2. First, second and third cars are white.
3. First, second and third car is white.

I do not wish to change the structure of the sentence. Unless none of them are correct, what is the closest possible correct form?

Comment: A better place for your question: http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have asked here as well: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89415/correct-grammar-when-listing-objects-with-an-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 2 is correct. You are referring to three distinct objects, so your noun and verb must both be plural. The noun and the verb must agree in number. The adjectives don't matter.

**Some more examples:**

My brother and sister *are* silly, but my mother *is* not.

My brothers *are* silly, but my sister *is* not.

**And now with adjectives:**

My pink and white dress *is* too small. (One dress)

My pink dress and my white dress *are* too small. (Two dresses)

My pink and white *dresses* *are* too small. (Two dresses)

My first dress *is* too small, but my second dress *is* too big. (One dress each)

My first dress *is* too small, but my other *dresses* *are* too big. (One dress, many dresses)

My first, second and third *dresses* *are* too small. (Three dresses)